# Blazor WebAssembly DeserializeUnableToConvertValue .NET 8 p5

Tags: windows, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

Anyone seen this error after upgrading to .NET 8 Preview 5? App fails to start due to this. I am not sure if its a caching problem but if it is its quite a big problem because we have a lot of users using the app and all of them won't be able to clear site data. Any suggestions what this is and how to resolve it?

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 System.AggregateException: AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage (An exception occurred executing JS interop: DeserializeUnableToConvertValue, System.Int32 Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 4.. See InnerException for more details.)
 ---> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: An exception occurred executing JS interop: DeserializeUnableToConvertValue, System.Int32 Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 4.. See InnerException for more details.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: DeserializeUnableToConvertValue, System.Int32 Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 4.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: InvalidCast, Null, number
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ExpectedNumber(JsonTokenType )
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.TryGetInt32(Int32& )
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetInt32()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.Int32Converter.Read(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , Int32& , Boolean& )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& , Utf8JsonReader& , Exception )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Deserialize(Utf8JsonReader& , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].DeserializeAsObject(Utf8JsonReader& , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsObject(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonTypeInfo )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.EndInvokeJS(Int64 , Boolean , Utf8JsonReader& )
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.<InvokeAsync>d__16`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHost.RunAsyncCore(CancellationToken , WebAssemblyCultureProvider )
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
callEntryPoint @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Comment: Does your project work fine locally? Does the problem only appear in iis? Please check the Event Viewer for related error messages.